# jquery defaultDate

Tags: jquery

i read the previous posts regarding all the defaultDate, and for some reason something doesnt work.

```
   $(function(){     
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({  
            inline: true,  
            showOtherMonths: true,  
            dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            defaultDate: new Date(2000,01,01) 
        });
    });
```

doesnt put any thing in the input even if it would've done something it was a default rather then NOW.

when im trying:

```
$(function(){ 
var currentDate = new Date();  

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({  
        inline: true,  
        showOtherMonths: true,  
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],  
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

    });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",currentDate); 
});
```

the page loads up with the datepicker already open (as if i clicked on it) and not even in the right place.

Update and solution:
thank you all, after reading all the implementations of all the versions of the ui, i found a workaround in css:

`.ui-datepicker { width: 17em; padding: .2em .2em 0; display: none; }`

Comment: Can you add your html markup? Does input `#datepicker` exist?

Comment: inline: true is the reason it appears as already open.

Comment: I try it on this fiddle, it's same to working well: http://jsfiddle.net/unt8Y/

Comment: the HTML:`<td width="190"><input style="width: 85px; color:#27AAE1; font-weight: bold; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;" type="text" id="datepicker" /></td>`

Comment: the inline doesnt seems to have any effect. i tried the fiddle too, you are right there it works well but there is somthing odd about my code

Comment: are you having some other jquery/javascript code which could override the datepicker plugin functionality?